# VHDL, if statements, and process names

Tags: vhdl

I've got two processes that handle the inputs and output of a single LVDS receiver on a design for an FPGA.  Now I need these same two processes concurrently repeated 8 times (for 8 separate LVDS receivers) with slightly different signal names (i.e. sigout1 vs. sigout0).  Is there any way I can accomplish this with a for loop?  Here are my two processes:

```
IBUFDS_inst : IBUFDS
    generic map (DIFF_TERM => FALSE,
                     IBUF_LOW_PWR => FALSE,
                     IOSTANDARD => "DEFAULT")
    port map (O => lvds_internal,
                 I => sigin0_p,
                 IB => sigin0_n);

    lvdsFlop:PROCESS(clk)
    BEGIN
        IF (clk = '1' AND clk'EVENT) THEN
            IF (reset_l = '0') THEN
                sigout0 <= '0';
            ELSE
                sigout0 <= lvds_internal;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;
```

I was hoping to use a for loop in the following way:

```
FOR i IN 0 TO 7 LOOP
    --Do the two processes, with signal names dependent on i:
    --sigout0 first iteration, sigout1 next iteration, etc for all
    --signals.
END LOOP;
```

If possible I'd like to have each of the processes name depend on i too (for simulation purposes) So I'd have IBUFDS_inst0, IBUFDS_inst1, etc. However, the above implementation does not pass a syntax check.

Edit: Thanks for the help guys, here is my updated VHDL:

```
    --Instantiate LVDS receivers and LVCMOS output for each channel
GEN_LVDS: FOR i IN sigout'RANGE GENERATE
BEGIN
    --Input LVDS buffer
    IBUFDS_inst : IBUFDS
    generic map (DIFF_TERM => FALSE,
                     IBUF_LOW_PWR => FALSE,
                     IOSTANDARD => "DEFAULT")
    port map (O => lvds_internal(i),
                 I => sigin_p(i),
                 IB => sigin_n(i));

END GENERATE GEN_LVDS;

--LVCMOS output flip-flop
    lvds_Flop:PROCESS(clk_fast)
    BEGIN
        IF (clk_fast = '1' AND clk_fast'EVENT) THEN
            IF (reset_l = '0') THEN
                sigout <= (others => '0');
            ELSE
                sigout <= lvds_internal;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS lvds_Flop;
```

Have not tested in hardware yet but it simulates well.

Answer (score 1):

*IBUFDS_inst* is a label, not a process name. You can't have it's name depends on *i*, but you can achieve what you want, and you will be able to distinguish between them.

To do that, *sigout*, *sigin_p*, *sigin_n* and *lvds_internal* must be **std_logic_vector** instead of std_logic. Here is a sample code:

```
entity lvds_test is
    port map (
        clk     : in  std_logic;
        reset_l : in  std_logic;
        sigin_p : in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        sigin_n : in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        sigout  : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end entity lvds_test;

architecture rtl of lvds_test is
    signal lvds_internal : std_logic_vector(sigin_p'range);
begin

LVDS_GEN: for i in lvds_internal'range generate
    IBUFDS_inst: IBUFDS
    generic map (
        DIFF_TERM    => FALSE,
        IBUF_LOW_PWR => FALSE,
        IOSTANDARD   => "DEFAULT"
    ) port map (
         O  => lvds_internal(i),
         I  => sigin_p(i),
         IB => sigin_n(i)
    );
end generate LVDS_GEN;

    lvdsFlop: process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if reset_l = '0' then
                sigout <= (others => '0');
            else
                sigout <= lvds_internal;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process lvdsFlop;
end architecture rtl;
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, this is exactly what I was looking for. One minor correction though, the lvdsFlop process should also be in the generate block (since lvds_internal is now a std_logic_vector with assignments dependent on i).  Also, Paebbels in his answer suggested using the "generate" keyword yet you seem to use "loop", is either syntax acceptable?

Comment: Yes, it was supposed to be 'generate', I made the correction. The *lvdsFlop* process doesn't mean to be in the generate statement. The generate is required to operate on individual bits, since IBUFDS doesn't support vectors. The *lvdsFlop* I used operates on a vector and doesn't need to be in the generate statement.

Comment: Oh one other thing, in simulation I am indeed able to distinguish between instances of my IBUFDS (e.g. LVDS_GEN(i).IBUFDS_inst refers to the ith LVDS buffer), but the lvdsFlop processes all have the same name and they float with all the other processes in the architecture block.  Any way to attach those processes to the generate block too?

Comment: There is a single *lvdsFlop* process. You can still acces invidual bits of the vectors.

Comment: Ah now I see what you mean, no need to have multiple processes since I can simply assign the vectors in one line.  Just requires a sigout <= (others => '0') for the reset.

Comment: Also fixed that, and exactly. I find it better that way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a generate statement:

```
gen :  for i in 0 to 7 generate
  [Optional: local signals]
begin
  [...]
  my : process(...)
  begin
    [...]
  end process;
end generate;
```

The full name of the process is now `gen[i].my`. Additionally, you should use vectors for your signals, so you can address them by index.

Comment: Yup forgot about the generate keyword, thanks for the template.  One thing though, although my component instantiations are now labeled as gen[i].my (or actually GEN_LVDS[i].IBUFDS_inst if you read my updated code), my lvdsFlop processes seem to be not attached to GEN_LVDS in the simulator. Instead they just float in the architecture block with all the other processes. Is that simulator-dependant?

Comment: One additional hint: If you are using ibufds and the process inside the generate loop you can declare lvds_internal locally between generate and begin in the generate loop as std_logic. This can clearup some code fragments.